# how to have unique selection to multiple dropdown fields?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I have 2 form fields (let it be A,B).Each have common dropdown options. How do I remove the option selected in A from dropdown list of options of B.

```
<Form.Item
                  name="B"
                  label="B"
                 
                >
                  <Select>
                    

                    
                    <Option value="1">1</Option>
                    <Option value="2">2</Option>
                    <Option value="3">3</Option>
                    <Option value="4">4</Option>
                   

                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>
              `
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable that will be shared for both.

*Assuming you are using a functional component*:

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([
  {key: 1, value: 1, disabled: false},
  {key: 2, value: 2, disabled: false}
])
```

*and while rendering*:

```
<Select>
  {options.map((opt, index) => <Option onClick={() => handleClick(index)} key={opt.key} disabled={opt.disabled}> {opt.value} </Option>
</Select>
```

*onClick:*

```
const handleClick = (index) => {
   const optionsCopy = [...options]
   optionsCopy[index].disabled = true
   setOptions(optionsCopy)
}
```

Now you can share the dropdown between the forms A and B.